# jquery modal fading issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some code for making a modal online, but when I try to implement the fading part it only works once and opens automatically unless I delete my part of the script. What could be the problem? Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

```
<h2>My Modal</h2>

<div id="fade" class="modal">
    <p>Thanks for clicking.</p>
    <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
</div>

<p><a href="#fade" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>

<script>
    $("#fade").modal({
        fadeDuration: 200,
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me with Chrome. Btw, the widget documentation can be found at https://jquerymodal.com/

The reason, why the dialog opens automatically is the `.modal()` function opens the dialog. Note, however, the definition of the anchor element with attribute 
`rel="modal:open"` attaches a handler which opens the dialog on click if dialog is in the closed state. So, calling `.modal()` is not required in your code and it causes opening the dialog when the page is loaded.

To set fading effects though, you can set the `$.modal.defaults` properties as required. I have compiled a working example based on your code with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WittigMarcus/hf2ygmw4/).

Comment: I would suggest not to override all the $.modal.defaults properties like you have done in your jsFiddle as it will remove the other essential properties also. Instead, just set the properties which are required.

For eg: 

$.modal.defaults.fadeDuration = 500;
$.modal.defaults.fadeDelay = 0.50;